# Change value of a state with 3 different buttons (React Native)

Tags: react-native, state

How can I dynamically change the value of a state when I click on one of the 3 buttons that I have, for example, I have button 1 with the value: 'State1' and I have button 2 with the value: 'state2', how can I do it? that when clicking on button one, the state takes the value of button 1 and when clicking on button 2, that state is replaced with the value of button 2, is this possible? Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

and show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.
When you press the buttons, they invoke onPress function.
You can use setState function inside the onPress.

Answer (score 0):

Going off your answer, it is only a matter of using the correct props (usually `onPress` for buttons) and updating your state's initial value.

```js
enum ReadLevel {
  Beginner = 'Beginner (1 to 6)',
  Intermediate = 'Intermediate (6 to 9)'
}

export function YourComponent() {
  const [readLevel, setReadLevel] = useState(ReadLevel.Beginner);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setReadLevel(ReadLevel.Beginner)}>
        <Text>
          {ReadLevel.Beginner}
        </Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setReadLevel(ReadLevel.Intermediate)}>
        <Text>
          {ReadLevel.Intermediate}
        </Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```